# Retrofit 2 for Android capabilities

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm interested if retrofit2 has:

- IPV6 support
- For HTTPS can we use SHA1 and suppress any warnings if a certificate is self signed?
- Android 2.2 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Android 2.2 support

Both [the docs](https://github.com/square/retrofit) and [the other docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) indicate that Retrofit requires Android 2.3.

The rest would be handled by OkHttp, such as via its [SSL configuration](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS). Note that you should validate self-signed certificates, not "suppress any warnings", because doing that will [get you kicked out of the Play Store and possibly sued](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/22/about-x509trustmanager-emails.html).

With regards to IPv6 support, it looks like OkHttp3 handles that.